# Background image should appear to the right of the text

Tags: css, struts2, displaytag

When I use the following CSS to add an image to the sortable field, it works but the image overlaps with the text that is already present. But I want the image to appear at the right of the text.

```
.sortable a{
   color:#FF9955;
   background-image: url(images/sorter.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;      
   background-position:right;         
}
```

This is my display tag

```
<display:column sortProperty="geo_region" title="Geographical Region" sortable="true">      
</display:column>
```

How will I make it appear to the right of the text?

Comment: Add `padding-right` to the `<a>` tag in the CSS with the same value as the width of the background image.

Answer (score 0):

add float left property to the text